# NPAPI plugin inject script

Tags: scripting, plugins, code-injection, npapi

I'm developing an npapi plugin. I am trying to inject a script into the current webpage of the browser,but am not able to do it. Any hints or suggestions as to how i should proceed with it, would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [NPN_Evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_Evaluate) to execute javascript source code.

If you want to 'inject a script' that's in a separate js file, use NPN_Evaluate to add a script tag to the document.  (Let me know if you need an example.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to interact with javascript, depending on what you're doing, is either NPN_Evaluate (if nothing else will work) or by using NPN_GetValue to get the NPObject for the DOM window and then you can call Invoke and SetProperty on that.

If you're just injecting straight javascript, of course, NPN_Evaluate is a good way to do that, but avoid using that on things that get called really often, as it does have a performance hit compared to talking to the dom objects directly.